# Is there any way to catch and handle drag & drop in Microsoft Teams

Tags: cloud, microsoft-teams

I am working on adding support for our cloud storage solution to MS Teams and I am looking at ways to do this.

It would be nice if it were possible to catch and handle a drag&drop event. This is what I would like to do:

1. The user drags a file into a Teams conversation.
2. Our app catches the event and, if the file is in our cloud, handles it and adds a link to the file. If the file was not in our cloud the event is handled in the usual way.

Is this possible?

Comment: Would an alternative be possible, to create a message extension (in this case one of those little buttons under the "compose" box)?

Comment: Yes, that is probably what I will do.

Comment: Ok. Let me know if you need any guidance on that. I added a more complete answer below, as I thought more about the message extension in this scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest creating a message extension (in this case one of those little buttons under the "compose" box). Other advantages to this are that the user can stay in Teams the whole time, and doesn't need to switch to another window. Also, they can use your "file picker" on any Teams platform (drag and drop will only work on their desktop). Finally, with your own picker, you can do [link unfurling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/link-unfurling?tabs=dotnet) to show something nicer to the user.